# При :hover на один элемент не появляется второй SCSS

Tags: html, css, sass, scss

Есть такая структура:

```css
#menu-icon:hover .menu ul {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.menu {
  ul {
    @include for-phone-only {
      margin-top: -1000px;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <svg id="menu-icon">Blalbla</svg>
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>Lallalal</li>
      <li>Lallalal</li>
      <li>Lallalal</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Хочу, что бы при наведении на **svg меню-иконку** на маленьких экранах выпрыгивало сверху меню. Меняю свойство `ul` списка с `margin-top: -1000 px` на `margin-top: 0px;` Использую **SCSS** и оно не работает, почему-то.

Если что, то я новичок + блондинка + теперь еще и в отчаянии.

Answer (score 1):

**Так , сообщество ru.stackoverflow не учит css и прочим IT технологиям для этого есть обучающие курсы и так же сайты**

Теперь по вашему вопросу ... 
Если не зная обычного так сказать ванильного css для чего вы лезете в препроцессоры ? Так же **если присутствует тег NAV то отпадает необходимость применения тега UL**, что бы вызвать блок рядом стоящий для события применяют обычные математические функции ,я применил **+** ... смотрите

```css
.menu {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s linear;
}

.putty:hover+.menu {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <p class="putty">My Event</p>
  <nav class="menu">
    <li>Lallalal</li>
    <li>Lallalal</li>
    <li>Lallalal</li>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Это работает при условии **если этот блок находится рядом**

*я убрал тег SVG из вашего примера так как SVG это не то что вы думаете...почитайте о нём*